# Best way to codificate/decodificate a data model without changing the model?

Tags: java, xml

I want to generate a xml representation of a data model, I dont want to modify my model addind something like JAXB and anotattions to describe it. 
I want a transparent and a flexible design.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit -  Ading Example

```
public class Figure {
private String name;
private String color;
public Figure(String name, String color) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

and it´s xml:

```
<Figure>
<name>square</name>
<color>red</color>
</Figure>
```

This is a trivial example, my real question is: 
how do I support a composition of objects or changes to the model without changing the "parser/coder/decoder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).
You would [create a custom Converter class](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html), and map your class (your model) to it using the canConvert() method.  If you're creating a custom Converter class, there are no need for annotations in your model class.

Answer (score 1):

Use [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html):

```
XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Test.xml")));
e.writeObject(new Figure("car", "blue"));
e.close();
```

Or take a look at [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/):

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xstream.alias("Figure", Figure.class);
String xml = xstream.toXML(new Figure("car", "blue"));
```

Comment: It was the first I found. Why not?

Comment: Thanks, I added this code to my example code and doesn´t work.
If there is no other answer i´ll try to get this work
thanks again!

Comment: @vfcosta No reason, just thought the implementation might have changed but it seems it hasn't, and 10 years have passed since jdk 1.4

Comment: @Kummo you have to write the default constructor (no args) for Figure class. But XMLEncoder do not generate xml as you expect in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

How about castor - http://www.castor.org/ ?